# Cannot implicilty convert 'Provider.Classes.CreditCard' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken'

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, exception, json.net

I have a class called CreditCard.  Here is its code:

Now, in a web service file, I am reading some data from the database and loading some of the fields of a CreditCard object.

Here is the code:

```
//get data from database

if (rdr.HasRows)
{
    CreditCard card_details = new CreditCard();

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        card_details.CardName = rdr["C_Name"].ToString();
        card_details.LastFour = rdr["Last_Four"].ToString();
    }
}

JObject obj = new JObject();
obj["Success"] = success;
obj["Card_Details"] = card_details;
```

The problem is that when I am passing the object as a JObject parameter in the second to last line, I am getting the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert 'Provider.Classes.CreditCard' to
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken'

Is there a workaround around this?  I am using the Newtonsoft JSON dll.  Thanks :)

**Update**

Doing this does not work.

```
obj["Card_Details"] = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken)card_details

It says: Cannot convert type ''Provider.Classes.CreditCard' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
JObject obj = (JObject)JToken.FromObject(card_details);
```

Here is the documentation for [JToken.FromObject](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/FromObject.htm)